# Release apk android in flutter is crashing on start up

Tags: android, firebase, dart, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I think my issue is because of Cloudfirestore that I am using inside my application. Some devices crash and some not.( S7 samsung verizon android 8.0 crashed, A5 samsung android 6.0 did not crash...). I used logcat to get the logs that are causing the crash and this is the error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Internal error in Firestore (0.6.6-dev).
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.obfuscated.zzgf.zzb(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@17.1.1:377)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.obfuscated.zzgk.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@17.1.1)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5302)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: io.grpc.ManagedChannelProvider$ProviderNotFoundException: No functional channel service provider found. Try adding a dependency on the grpc-okhttp or grpc-netty artifact
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.obfuscated.zzgf.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@17.1.1:288)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.obfuscated.zzgi.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@17.1.1)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:390)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:153)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:267)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.obfuscated.zzgf$zza.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@17.1.1:203)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
     Caused by: io.grpc.ManagedChannelProvider$ProviderNotFoundException: No functional channel service provider found. Try adding a dependency on the grpc-okhttp or grpc-netty artifact
        at io.grpc.ManagedChannelProvider.provider(ManagedChannelProvider.java:60)
        at io.grpc.ManagedChannelBuilder.forTarget(ManagedChannelBuilder.java:70)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.obfuscated.zzfk.<init>(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@17.1.1:101)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.obfuscated.zzm.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@17.1.1:1216)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.obfuscated.zzt.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@17.1.1)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.obfuscated.zzgf.zzc(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@17.1.1:309)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.obfuscated.zzgj.call(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@17.1.1)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.obfuscated.zzgf.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@17.1.1:285)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.obfuscated.zzgi.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@17.1.1) 
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:390) 
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:153) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:267) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573) 
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.obfuscated.zzgf$zza.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@17.1.1:203) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

so how to resolve such an error in flutter ??

Comment: Update your Gradle dependencies. Firestore is at 17.1.5 now and I bet others are outdated too.

Comment: Make sure you have registered the release API key

Comment: @TheWanderer I know that I should update it but where to update it?

Comment: @Brans I jave registered my key but I want to update my gradle.how to do so ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Had the same issue with some phones like Samsung S5. The app started crashing when I tried to open it. Here is a fix that worked for me:

```
defaultConfig {
    ...
    multiDexEnabled true
    ndk {
        abiFilters 'x86', 'armeabi-v7a'
    }
}
```

Had to add `ndk` in `android/app/build.gradle` file and it worked like a charm.

I hope this can help someone.

Answer (score 0):

you should check first if you have installed the latest [cloud_firestore](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/cloud_firestore#-versions-tab-) package (0.8.2+3) in your pubspec.yaml

you can upgrade the google services under `<yourapp>/android/build.gradle` (current version 4.2.0). But be aware that you maybe need to upgrade the other plugins as well to the newest version there.

Comment: Do you have a list that show the gradle version and its corresponding compatible google plugin

Comment: I already have the latest version of cloud firestore but the problem still persists, can this be because of grpc error appearing in the logcat I have provided up

Comment: Try adding a dependency on the grpc-okhttp or grpc-netty artifact , maybe this

Comment: where have you added the dependency for grpc? into your gradle file under android or android/app/ ?

Comment: I did not add it anywhere. Where should I add it?